# jQuery on button click, redirect on the same page but to a different section/panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, once I click my button, I would like to redirect my page to the SAME page, but to a different section/panel in the page. Been scratching my head trying to figure out how to do this for a while now. 
Here's my code;

## Button

```
<div class="col-xs-12 padd0" id="footer" style="text-align:center">
     <a href="#"><img src="./assets/images/button.png" id="btn1"></a>
</div>
```

## Panel/Section

```
<div id="panel2" class="panel" style="padding-top:120px; position:relative">
     <p>Redirect to this section</p>
</div>
```

## Script

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
            if($('[name="name"]').val() == '' || $('[name="cifno"]').val() == '' || $('[name="nric"]').val() == '' || $('[name="identityno"]').val() == ''
            || $('[name="expirydate"]').val() == '' || $('[name="dora"]').val() == '')
            {
                alert("fill up stuff");
            }else{
                window.location = "#panel2";
                $("#img1").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_1.png");
                $("#img2").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_2.png");
                $("#img3").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_1.png");
                $("#img4").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_1.png");
                $("#img5").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_1.png");
                $("#img6").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_1.png");
                $("#img7").attr("src", "./assets/images/bullet_1.png");
            }
});
```

So from the else condition from the if statement, I would like to redirect myself to `#panel2` how do I do this?

**Edit #1**:
I know that I can redirect it on my `<a href="#">` tag; but this does not cater for what I need. I'm redirecting it on my script section as I have a basic checker to check if some fields are filled out, that's why I can't set `<a href="#panel2">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$('#btn1').click( function(e) {e.preventDefault(); /*your_code_here;*/ return false; });`

Comment: errr what would this be for? like if I use a button instead of `<a href>` ?

Comment: This code is to prevent default a href click, put your  jquery code inside this block.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 padd0" id="footer" style="text-align:center">
 <a href="#panel2"><img src="./assets/images/button.png" id="btn1"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: i think it should be `href='#panel2' `

Comment: ok so this redirects without going through my checker. the thing is I want it to redirect via jquery. :/

Comment: so based on my code, the script part, I have a checker to check for some basic validation stuff, only if it passes, would i want the page to redirect. by setting `<a href="#panel2">` it redirects without checking it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `a` as a link, i.e. `href` is either empty or `#`, use a `button` instead: https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/#article-header-id-2.

To answer your question, in your onclick handler, after doing the necessary validation, you can do `window.location.hash = 'panel2'` to redirect to that panel.

Comment: The reason as to why I'm not using a button here, is as there are multiple forms in the page, not just one, hence the redirection to a different section. Also, `window.location.hash = 'panel2'` does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **panel2** on href. Like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 padd0" id="footer" style="text-align:center">
 <a href="#panel2"><img src="./assets/images/button.png" id="btn1"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but refer to my Edit#1; I can't add it there.